# Xcode Missing build setting: BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION

Tags: xcode, frameworks, build-settings

When I was trying to build a framework, I found the build setting BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION is missing in my project.

Thought may related to particular project, so I start a new one, but still not seen.

[image]

To make sure, I download another project from kodeco's[Creating a Framework for iOS](https://www.kodeco.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios) tutorial, and the setting option shows!

Why does it not showing on my own project?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my end.

Try the following solution:

Navigate to your General Settings => Build Settings

Make sure you have "All" checked off, instead of the default "Basic", or in your case "Customized"

This solved it for my end. :)

[Screenshot of the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV9vt.png)

Comment: I'm not sure your "have "All" checked off, instead of the default "Basic", or in your case "Customized" " means, not recall set any build setting option to customize